# Why is a .bacpac file so small compared to a .bak file of the same database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, import, export

I've been doing backups of my SQL Server 2014 Express databases for import to other servers and noticed a difference in file size between `.bacpac` and `.bak`.

Why is a `.bacpac` file so small compared to a `.bak` file of the same database?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A

- `.bacpac` file = Schema + Data. Note that Data is BCP'ed out using Native format (not readable by Human).

  - You can rename the `.bacpac` to `.zip` to see the actual contents.
  - You can use [`...DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) commandline to extract the `.bacpac` contents programatically.
  - It is a **snapshot** that includes User data + Schema from SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.

-

- [Backup (commonly have `.bak` extension)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx) = A FULL database backup contains a complete copy of database and provides a single point-in-time to which the database can be restored. A full backup contains some transaction log records so that the restored component (database, file, or filegroup) can be made transactionally consistent.

**A `BACPAC` is not a substitute for a FULL backup.** Its just a snapshot that can be used to move a database from one server to another (or to cloud) and [archiving an existing database in an open format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx).

From my test, below are the results

[image]

Comment: The log file is probably the biggest reason for the size difference.

Comment: I'd assume there's no index data in the .bacpac either, which is likely to be a BIG contributor to file size.

Comment: Why do you say that is it not a substitute for a FULL backup please? And what exactly is the purpose of doing a BACPAK file please?

Answer (score 2):

A backup created via the `BACKUP DATABASE` command (`.bak`) is a page-by-page copy of a database. Note that SQL Server database contains not only data pages. There are also pages with indexes that can be large. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide)

A backup created using the Export Data-Tier Application (`.bacpac`)  operation is simply an exported rows from a database in XML format placed in an archive. You can manually view the contents of BACPAC, just change the extension of this file to .zip.

**The size of the `.bacpac` file is directly proportional to the number of records in a database (taking into account the compression ratio).**

**The size of the `.bak` file depends not only on the data but also on the size of the indexes.**

Sometimes this can be a problem, check for example this old [discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/1/how-to-exclude-indexes-from-backups-in-sql-server-2008)

Therefore, the `.bacpac` file is usually smaller in size.

I ran the simplest tests with the [AdventureWorks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15) database and got these results.

```
AdventureWorks.bacpac - 17 mb
AdventureWorks.bacpac.zip - 16 mb
AdventureWorks_with_compression.bak - 49 mb
AdventureWorks_with_compression.bak.zip - 47 mb
```

**Should I use .bacpac to reduce my backup size?**

**No.**

Export \ Import Data Tier Application has several significant drawbacks that are critical for large databases:

1. This is not a transactionally consistent operation. The tables are
   exported sequentially. There may be a problem with the foreign key.
   This is doubly bad because you only discover it when you try to
   recover. Therefore, when performing this operation, you need to take
   a snapshot of the database and export the snapshot.
2. It takes much longer for both export and import. At the moment when
   you urgently need to run a restore, you will not be able to do this
   because the restore from .bacpac will take several hours to
   complete.
3. Export can significantly load the server, especially for large
   tables, which, together with the previous point, makes regular
   backups a dubious decision.

Classic backup created using the `BACKUP DATABASE` command is devoid of these drawbacks, to save space use [Point-in-time recovery](https://sqlbak.com/academy/point-in-time-recovery)

Export \ Import data-tier application can be considered as a way to create a backup only for small databases, in those cases when you do not have access to the file system. In this case, do not export the live database under any circumstances, be sure to create a snapshot for consistent export.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the biggest difference is the data is compressed (using zip) for the `.bacpac` file which is not the case with a normal `.bak` file.
Just compress the `.bak` file and see that it's a lot smaller ;)