# What are the .BCP files inside a .bacpak file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bacpac

Diving on dba.stackexchange.com I found a [nice answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137993/why-is-a-bacpac-file-so-small-compared-to-a-bak-file-of-the-same-database) that teach me how to open a `.bacpac` file with File Explorer.

I gave it a try with the database `AdventureWorks2008R2` and all I did was:

1. Save the database as `.bacpac` file
2. Rename the file extension to `.zip`
3. Unzip it

And there you go, you can see the tables of the database as folders and inside each folder you can see the raw data.

[image]

But when I open the folder `Person.Address` I see there are 38 files into it with extension `.BCP`.

[image]

At the beginning I taught they were the pages in which the data are split. But those cannot be pages because they weight about `67KB`. Pages should weight `8KB`.

So I checked the number of pages with this query:

```
-- Total # of pages, used_pages, and data_pages for a given heap/clustered index
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) AS TotalPages, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) AS UsedPages, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) AS UnusedPages
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

And I found out that the `Person.Address` table has `689` pages.

So what are those 38 `.BCP` files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The data in a `BACPAC` file is exported from the database using the [Bulk Copy (BCP) Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility). From the docs:

> The bulk copy program utility (bcp) bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format. The bcp utility can be used to import large numbers of new rows into SQL Server tables or to export data out of tables into data files.

`BACPAC` files contain data that is exported using BCP's "native" file format, which is a binary type file. The data for the table is simply exported across multiple files, rather than one big file. If you look through the `.bcp` files across different tables, you'll find that the file size will vary, with skew in size related to variation in different rows having different data width. For example, when I create a `bacpac` of AdventureWorks, the `.bcp` files for `Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail` range from 39kb to 62kb.

BCP (and thus `BACPAC` generation) does not back up data by copying data pages like a standard backup, but rather is doing table-level querying & exporting.

Comment: Every now and then I come back to this reply and it always amaze me. Thank you @AMtwo